# Setting a dateTime property to null

Tags: c#

I have this class which is a nuget package with a nullable dateTime property. This property is set depending on when another property is filled. Now, I do not want this property to have this property and I will like to set it null. Here is the class in the private nuget package

```
public class myClass 
{
   private string _todaysDate;

   public DateTime? todaysDateAsDateTime
   {
     get
     {
       DateTime? result;
       return !this.todaysDate.TryParseToDate(out result) ? new DateTime?() : result;
     }
     set => this.todaysDate = value.ParseToDate();
   }
   
   public string todaysDate
   {
     get => this._todaysDate;
     set => this._todaysDate= value;
   }
}
```

ParseToDate and TryParseToDate are extension menthods in thesame nuget

```
public static string ParseToDate(this DateTime? value) => value?.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd", (IFormatProvider) CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

public static bool TryParseToDate(this string value, out DateTime? result)
    {
      if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
      {
        result = new DateTime?();
        return true;
      }
      bool flag = false;
      DateTime result1 = DateTime.UtcNow;
      if (value.Length == 10)
        flag = DateTime.TryParseExact(value, "yyyy-MM-dd", (IFormatProvider) CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out result1);
      if (flag)
      {
        result = new DateTime?(DateTime.SpecifyKind(result1, DateTimeKind.Utc));
        return true;
      }
      result = new DateTime?();
      return false;
    }
```

when using this class, is there a possibility of setting todaysDateAsDateTime to null? because I do not want to have this value. The todaysDate is filled by the program when I use it in my application

Comment: Why don't you just ignore the property and pretend it doesn't exist?

Comment: Yes, just manage the case when `value` is null, like `set => this.todaysDate = value?.ParseToDate();`

Comment: @Llama It is filled automatically since todaysDateAsDateTime depends on todaysDate. @vernou is there another way of setting `todaysDateAsDateTime ` to null without changing the class? because I would like to have just `todaysDate `

Comment: No, you need modify the code because `((DateTime?)null).ParseToDate` will always throw null reference exception. But you can have one field to many properties. See my answer.

Comment: It isn't filled automatically. It is computed when you access it. Why do you want it to be null?

Comment: I am writing the filled values to a file and only the filled values are written

Comment: Then you'll want to create a wrapper for the class that doesn't contain the field, or you'll want to find a way to exclude it from being written. You can't change the class in an assembly you don't control.

Answer (score -1):

In the property `todaysDateAsDateTime`, you need manage case in get/set when the value is null :

```cs
public class myClass 
{
    private string _todaysDate;

    public DateTime? todaysDateAsDateTime
    {
        get => 
            this._todaysDate != null && this._todaysDate.TryParseToDate(out DateTime? result) ?
                result : null;
        set => this._todaysDate = value?.ParseToDate();
    }

    public string todaysDate
    {
        get => this._todaysDate;
        set => this._todaysDate = value;
    }
}
```

I think you begin with C#, I add the same code without sugar syntax :

```cs
public class myClass 
{
    private string _todaysDate;

    public DateTime? todaysDateAsDateTime
    {
        get
        {
            DateTime? result;
            if(this._todaysDate!=null && this.todaysDate.TryParseToDate(out result))
            {
                return result;
            }
            else
            {
                null;
            }
        }
        set
        {
            if(value != null)
            {
                this._todaysDate = value.ParseToDate();
            }
            else
            {
                this._todaysDate = null;
            }
        }
    }

    public string todaysDate
    {
        get => this._todaysDate;
        set => this._todaysDate = value;
    }
}
```